# How to start WSL cron jobs on boot?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some scripts that must be run under WSL, and must be run all the time. Currently, my Windows 11 randomly decides when it thinks it's convenient to reboot and install some updates. Is there a way to start WSL cron jobs automatically with Windows?

If this sounds like an XY Problem, I'd be more than happy to elaborate further.

I set up the cron job via crontab -e (and also sudo). I was expecting it to behave as it would on a regular Linux distro, but it doesn't do anything until I "sudo service cron start" and have at least one of the WSL windows open.

Comment: If the only issue is starting the cron service with Windows, [this](https://superuser.com/a/1514776) might help.

Comment: @FiddlingAway Sorry for the late response, but that did the trick, thank you! I had to optimize it some more for my needs, but you've given me the right direction. I would gladly accept your answer,

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it. As for the answer, don't worry about it. You can +1 the one in the link I posted, and you can post your own answer here, to show how you solved it in your specific case (modifications and all).